# Can the stock market show indefinite exponential growth?

Tags: stock-market, value, resource-economics

In a comments on a [question on money.SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/81126/why-should-we-expect-stocks-to-go-up-in-the-long-term), the following dialog took place:

> Eventually there will not be enough matter to represent all the money, so we know for certain that the answer is "No" for a long enough term.

--yters

> What do you mean by "represent?" Do you mean that we won't be able to build computer chips that can store a digital representation of someone's stock income? Do you mean that we will no longer be able to cash out our stock portfolio into a fixed commodity like gold, at a fixed dollar price? The former seems wrong to me, and the latter irrelevant.

-- BenCrowell

> @BenCrowell: the stock market is not abstract, it depends on investors expectations on the real economy. Its obvious that the economy cannot grow forever, as the planet (and its resources) are finite.

-- Martin Argerami

I'm not convinced by the argument that Martin Argerami claims is obvious. It seems to me to rest on a false assumption that value is measured by resources, e.g., that a dollar's "true" value is measured by how many milligrams of gold it can buy. But I'm not an economist. Would anyone like to take a shot at explaining who is right?

Comment: We have inflation which seems to be indefinite and exponentialyl growing. Do you maybe mean inflation adjusted capitalizations on the stock market? Then I would say only if there are equally large debts somewhere else.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

May I rephrase your question into the broader question **"Can economic growth continue indefinitely?"**

(In response to objections that eventually the sun will burn out or the universe will suffer heat death, I take **indefinite** to mean "lasting for an unknown or unstated length of time" ([OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/indefinite)). So I am thinking of 100s, 1000s, or even 10000s of years ahead. But I am **not** thinking of billions of years ahead or the "infinite future".)

Non-economists commonly believe the answer to be "no", giving some reason along the lines of "resources are finite!"

But the economist's answer to this is **"Yes, of course economic growth can continue indefinitely."** And so to answer also your narrower question, **"Yes, of course the stock market can show indefinite exponential growth."** (By "can", I mean that this is at least conceivable. Whether it *will* is a different matter altogether. After all the world might end tomorrow in a nuclear apocalypse.)

I think we can distinguish between **two common fallacies** at work here.

---

**Fallacy #1. "Economic growth is about making ever more "stuff", digging ever more gold and other natural resources out of the ground, burning ever more energy, etc."** (This caricature is perhaps why many non-economists and especially environmentalists are averse to economists and the idea of economic growth.) The fallacy typically continues, "Resources/the universe is finite. Therefore economic growth must also be finite."

But this is wrong. **Economic growth is about improving human well-being, broadly conceived.**

It is true that for a long time (the past few centuries), improvements in human well-being were largely through improvements in **material** well-being and highly-correlated with making ever more stuff and burning ever more energy. After all, it was not two centuries ago that the vast majority of mankind lived at bare subsistence level. (Indeed, even today, many people still do.)

But going forward, it is perfectly conceivable that we make ever less "stuff", dig ever less "stuff" out of the ground, and burn ever less energy, and yet still become ever more well-off. This is actually already happening today in the rich countries (see e.g. falling energy use, briefly analyzed below).

Since the 1930s and 1940s, we've measured economic growth mostly by GDP growth. But economists have always recognized that GDP is a very flawed measure of well-being. Economists are working on alternatives that better capture the notion of improvements in human well-being or equivalently, economic welfare. I do not expect that in 100 years, the current concept of GDP without fundamental modifications will still be used to as the primary measure of economic well-being.

(Footnote: Perhaps in the future, we will also include non-human well-being in our conception of economic growth. But for now, we still restrict attention mostly to human well-being.)

---

**Fallacy #2. "Bad things (like the consumption of food or resources) will grow rapidly or even exponentially. In contrast, offsetting good things (like technology) can at best grow arithmetically. Therefore, there are necessarily limits to growth."**

This fallacy is not new. Here's an example of doom-and-gloom predictions from each of the past three centuries, all of which proved to be wrong.

- [Malthus (1798): *An Essay on the Principle of Population*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_on_the_Principle_of_Population).

[2010 commentary](http://www.crf-usa.org/bill-of-rights-in-action/bria-26-2-the-debate-over-world-population-was-malthus-right.html):

> Malthus began with two “fixed laws of our nature.” First, men and
>   women cannot exist without food. Second, the “passion between the
>   sexes” drives them to reproduce.
>
> He explained that, if unchecked, people breed “geometrically” (1, 2,
>   4, 8, 16, etc.). But, he continued, the production of food can only
>   increase “arithmetically” (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.). “The natural
>   inequality of the two powers of population and of [food] production in
>   the earth,” he declared, “form the great difficulty that to me appears
>   insurmountable [impossible to overcome].”
>
> Malthus concluded: “I see no way by which man can escape from the
>   weight of this law.” In other words, if people keep reproducing in an
>   uncontrolled geometric manner, they will eventually be unable to
>   produce enough food for themselves. **The future, Malthus argued,
>   pointed not to endless improvement for humanity, but to famine and
>   starvation.**

- [The Great Horse Manure Crisis of 1894](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjdiu_hsdjUAhUIQ48KHWh9Ay8QFggrMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffee.org%2Ffiles%2FdocLib%2F547_32.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGsuk7ZKFTBl0KCkGd0LOT_o4eHuQ):

> Writing in the Times of London in 1894, one writer estimated that in 50 years every street in London would be buried under nine feet of manure. Moreover, all these horses had to be stabled, which used up ever-larger areas of increasingly valuable land. And as the number of horses grew, ever-more land had to be devoted to producing hay to feed them (rather than producing food for people), and this had to be brought into cities and distributed—by horse-drawn vehicles. **It seemed that urban civilization was doomed.**

- In 1972, exactly such a book title was published: [*The Limits to Growth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Limits_to_Growth):

> **Our attempts to use even the most optimistic estimates of the benefits of technology in the model did not prevent the ultimate decline of population and industry, and in fact did not in any case postpone the collapse beyond the year 2100** (p. 145.).

This was a highly-influential best-seller that has [sold over 16M copies in over 30 languages](https://www.clubofrome.org/news/publication-of-the-limits-to-growth/).

Take their example of gold. On p. 56, they calculate that if gold use continued growing exponentially AND there was 5 times as much gold available as there were known gold reserves (they thought this was a very optimistic assumption), **gold would be depleted in 29 years, or in 2001**.

Surprisingly, 2001 came and went and gold continued to be mined. Indeed, more than ever. Gold mining graph ([source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/World_Gold_Production_1900-2014.png)):

[image]

Roughly every 5 years since 1972, *The Limits to Growth* folks (AKA the Club of Rome) have released a new update to their 1972 book, each time explaining why they had been correct all along (of course) and sometimes pushing back their predictions about when the eventual collapse will set in. In their [*30-Year Update*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/193149858X), they make no mention whatsoever of gold.

The following is the [response](https://books.google.com/books?id=X_TjAAAAMAAJ&q=%22The%20authors%20load%20their%20case%20by%20letting%20some%20things%20grow%20exponentially%22&dq=%22The%20authors%20load%20their%20case%20by%20letting%20some%20things%20grow%20exponentially%22) by two critics to *The Limits to Growth*, also quoted by Robert Solow in a *Newsweek* article:

> The authors load their case by letting some things grow exponentially
>   and others not. Population, capital and pollution grow exponentially
>   in all models, but technologies for expanding resources and
>   controlling pollution are permitted to grow, if at all, only in
>   discrete increments.

(Footnote: Doomsday-mongering was especially fashionable in the West around the 1970s. See also the famous [Simon-Ehrlich wager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon%E2%80%93Ehrlich_wager) at around the same time.

Predictions at the polar extremes capture the public's attention. [Ray Kurzweil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_Kurzweil) comes to mind as someone who makes similar predictions, but at the polar opposite.

In contrast, the median economist is cautiously optimistic, believing merely that slow but steady, sustained growth is possible. No doomsday, no stagnation, but no [impending Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity) either. Not exactly a position that sells many books.)

---

In 2012, a physics professor wrote a somewhat-influential blogpost: [Exponential Economist Meets Finite Physicist](https://dothemath.ucsd.edu/2012/04/economist-meets-physicist/), exhibiting both of the above fallacies. That someone as intelligent as a physics professor could commit both fallacies shows that economists must do a far better job at educating the public.

There is plenty that is wrong in that blogpost and perhaps I will do a sentence-by-sentence dissection elsewhere, but this is probably not the proper avenue. Here I'll merely point out one obvious factual error that's of particular relevance. He claims as fact that

> energy growth has far outstripped population growth, so that
>   **per-capita energy use has surged dramatically over time**—our energy
>   lives today are far richer than those of our great-great-grandparents
>   a century ago [economist nods]. So **even if population stabilizes, we
>   are accustomed to per-capita energy growth: total energy would have to
>   continue growing to maintain such a trend [another nod].**

As [Tim Harford](http://freakonomics.com/2014/01/24/can-economic-growth-continue-forever-of-course/) points out, this is FALSE. In recent decades, energy growth per person in many countries has actually been falling, even as GDP per capita has risen. Graph (data from [World Bank, June 1st 2017 update](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/EG.USE.PCAP.KG.OE)):

[image]

In every rich country, per-capita energy use peaked years ago and has been falling ever since. In fact, in some countries, it peaked DECADES ago (peaked in 1978 in the US, in 1979 in Germany, and in 1973 in the UK).

(One would've hoped that a physics professor backed up his factual claims with something more than a fictitious and bumbling economist who repeatedly nods.)

See also falling energy intensity (energy use per unit of GDP) ([source](https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=27032)):

[image]

The highest per-capita energy use ever attained was the US in 1978. My prediction is that global average human well-being will keep improving, but global per-capita energy use will never hit the US 1978 peak (at least not until we start populating other planets and stars).

Comment: Which trap are you referring to exactly, when you talk about the "Exponential Economist Meets Finite Physicist" article? You should be very specific in pointing what the supposed logical flaws are. You think that this non-economist (Tom Murphy) doesn't understand economy? Well, he thinks most economists don't understand physics. And he does try to prove that the economy cannot be completely decoupled from the physical world.

Comment: Important part from the article : " If the flow of energy is fixed, but we posit continued economic growth, then GDP continues to grow while energy remains at a fixed scale. This means that energy—a physically-constrained resource, mind—must become arbitrarily cheap as GDP continues to grow and leave energy in the dust."

Comment: Another one : "But if energy became arbitrarily cheap, someone could buy all of it, and suddenly the activities that comprise the economy would grind to a halt. Food would stop arriving at the plate without energy for purchase, so people would pay attention to this. Someone would be willing to pay more for it. Everyone would. There will be a floor to how low energy prices can go as a fraction of GDP."

Comment: When the non-economist says "Heat death of the universe" what does the economist say?

Comment: While it is true that material wealth is not a great indicator of well being, that is what the stock market measures. *The fact that it isn't the greatest thing to measure doesn't change the fact that is what it **actually** measures*.  In what way is saying that maybe one day "the market will completely transform and start measuring something completely different than what it does now" *not* the same thing as saying **No, it can't continue on forever**??

Comment: Is the concept of an infinite capacity to experience well being meaningful both conceptually and practically? Because "Indefinite Exponential Growth in Human Well Being" obviously requires such an infinite capacity. Conceptually, it doesn't make much sense. And on a practical level, can a finite being experience infinite *anything*??

Comment: @EricDuminil: The trap is to believe that economic growth must always somehow be tied to an increase in energy use. More broadly, as stated a couple times in my answer above, the trap is the common layperson's misconception that economic growth is about making ever more "stuff", digging ever more "stuff" out of the ground, and burning ever more energy and "stuff".

Comment: @EricDuminil: Unfortunately the "important part" you quote has so many things wrong. It is complete nonsense and a complete misunderstanding of how the price mechanism works. E.g. the syllogism "If energy is fixed and GDP keeps growing, then the price of energy must fall to zero (or "become arbitrarily cheap" in his wording)" is false and I don't know how he even came up with that reasoning.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Also, if some commodity X is such that if someone bought all of it, this would "grind the economy to a halt", then this commodity is scarce and therefore will not be arbitrarily cheap. Either it is infinitely abundant (not scarce), which is the only way that its price can be zero; or it is scarce, in which case its price will not be zero.

Comment: @KennyLJ: Your last point seems to be exactly the one written in the Tom Murphy's article. It's a proof by contradiction that energy cannot be arbitrarily cheap.

Comment: @EricDuminil: His "proof by contradiction" depends on the syllogism which, as I pointed out above, is false. His reasoning goes: "If energy is fixed and GDP keeps growing, then the price of energy must fall to zero." (False.) "But the price of energy can never fall to zero." (Actually this is also false.) "Therefore — proof by contradiction — GDP cannot keep growing." (False.)

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, your point is that the [energy elasticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_elasticity) can be smaller than 1, and that it can still decrease in the future. This is correct. But to prove that the stock market or the GDP can grow infinitely, you actually need to prove that the energy elasticity can tend to 0, and that it can tend to 0 faster than the GDP tends to ∞. The burden of proof is on you, because you're the one claiming that an infinite growth is possible in a finite world. Tom Murphy only needs to show that the elasticity is larger than an ε.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Actually energy intensity has actually been negative! That is, energy use per unit of GDP has been falling. [Source.](https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=27032) And in some countries, energy elasticity has not only been smaller than 1, but negative (GDP has risen while energy use has fallen). Please see also my updated answer, which now has a shiny graph depicting how energy use has actually peaked in most rich countries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your update. Now we're talking about concrete facts! For your energy per capita graph, note that China & India are still steadily growing, and they contribute to almost half of the population. See https://ourworldindata.org/energy-production-and-changing-energy-sources/ The global consumption per capita has been growing, but it's true that it doesn't mean it will always do so.

Comment: Yes, energy elasticity (not intensity) has been negative in some countries. It doesn't mean it can be arbitrary close to 0 indefinitely while the GDP is growing : which is what you (still) need to prove.

Comment: Ok, if "indefinite" to an economist means "several decades" then I can see why the get into so many disagreements with non-economists. Like how the word "theory" means "wild guess" to a non scientists yet means "the body of knowledge we consider to be undisputable fact". In that case, considering the OP was asking about an economists view, I retract most of my questions.

Comment: Except the question about how the stock market doesn't measure happiness. If the stock market is measuring things other than human well being -- and it does. And the thing that can actually increase at the rates we need it to is human well being, how do you draw your conclusion? "If the stock market mutates into something that is unrecognizable as the stock market is today, then yes it can continue on for the next indefinite while."

Comment: Oh, and the flip side of those charts showing a flatline in energy use, are the charts that show wages and most other economic metrics (you know 'well being') as flat in those countries over that time period as well. Doesn't that hurt your argument that these two things are completely disconnected?

Comment: The only thing that world energy intensity curve proves is that we get less for our bucks. Basically it shows the real inflation. If you take imports into account rich countries still have a GDP that is perfectly correlated 99% according to data, to energy. https://imgur.com/a/Umxe3dk  you can't conveniently use confounding factors to suit your narrative

Comment: I feel like your 2 fallacies and the critique of the blog are refutable. For example, #1 is actually a reversal of what I'm used to, environmentalists prone a different benchmark than GDP. You turned around the accusation. For #2 you only demonstrated by data that we pushed the limit momentarily (eg by increasing crop yield. ..thanks to finite resources) but haven't demonstrated the model wrong. You are a Fat Tony in the standoff against Doctor Jones. The depressed graph since US peak oil in my view corroborates why US minimal hour wage is 40% less than in the 70's.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, one needs to know a little economics and a little physics. I only really know anything about the former. That caveat aside, stock market values and GDP are metrics that reflect productive activity. Some vector of inputs $\mathbf{x}$ (n.b. these need not be material resources) are subjected to a production process yielding outputs $f(\mathbf{x})$ (n.b. this output also does not need to be in material consumables).

There are two ways to increase economic output (i.e., to achieve economic growth).

- The first is to increase the supply of inputs to $\mathbf{y}>\mathbf{x}$. This is the pre-industrial mode of econmic development: work harder, extract more resources, cultivate more land, and thereby produce more stuff.
- The second way to increase growth is to develop a new production technology, $g$, such that $g(\mathbf{x})>f(\mathbf{x})$ (more is produced with the same inputs). For example, computers allow us to produce more output from fewer inputs than do typewriters. Indeed, if technology improves at a sufficient rate then it is (theoretically) possible to sustain exponential economic growth even as the the consumption of inputs *decreases* faster than exponentially.

---

In the extreme long-run, this observation interacts with the laws of physics (brace yourself for hand-waving). Provided there is some region of the universe that is not in a state of maximum entropy then there is scope for humans to effect a process of production and, with sufficiently advanced technology, for this production to grow exponentially (note: the claim is not that it will happen or that it is likely, only that there does not seem to be anything in either economics or physics that makes it fundamentally impossible).

On the other hand, if the entire universe converges to a uniform state of maximum entropy (commonly known as heat death) then, roughly, continuation of economic growth would require $f(\mathbf{0})>\mathbf{0}$—i.e. that valuable outputs spontaneously emerge from a fully entropic system. This seems implausible and probably contradicts the first law of thermodynamics.

---

So my assessment of the situation is as follows:

> **Q:** must the economy's long-run rate of economic growth eventually be less than exponential *as a matter of theoretical necessity*?
>
> **A:** If the universe converges to a uniform state of maximum entropy then yes, otherwise no.

This leaves the question of the long-run fate of the universe. To end on a note of optimism, here's a quote from Wikipedia:

> "The role of entropy in cosmology remains a controversial subject since the time of Ludwig Boltzmann. Recent work has cast some doubt on the heat death hypothesis and the applicability of any simple thermodynamic model to the universe in general. Although entropy does increase in the model of an expanding universe, the maximum possible entropy rises much more rapidly, moving the universe further from the heat death with time, not closer. This results in an "entropy gap" pushing the system further away from the posited heat death equilibrium. Other complicating factors, such as the energy density of the vacuum and macroscopic quantum effects, are difficult to reconcile with thermodynamical models, making any predictions of large-scale thermodynamics extremely difficult."

Comment: You could stop your argument right after "Indeed, if technology improves at a sufficient rate then it is (theoretically) possible to sustain exponential economic growth even as the the consumption of inputs decreases faster than exponentially.". Done! The answer to the question is therefore : No.

Comment: This might not be a popular opinion on this website, but here goes : the economy is based on a physical world. It means that it's fine to talk about economics with only physics knowledge, but it's not okay to apply economics principle to the physical world.

Comment: @EricDuminil I'm not sure how you can conclude the answer is no from the quoted statement, which is a statement only about what is possible not what is not. Note that I am not trying to argue that growth can continue for ever (in fact, I think it cannot for reasons that, indeed, are physical in nature), but you have identified the wrong step in the argument as the key part.

Comment: @EricDuminil Also, the claim that it is fine to talk about economics with only physics knowledge is ridiculous. Physics might say something about the infinite-horizon outcome, but tells us virtually nothing about macroeconomic phenomena at meaningful time scales, and absolutely nothing about phenomena in other branches of economics.

Comment: I took the quoted statement because the included "if" is so big that it isn't realistically possible. Many technological processes are pretty close to the theoretical efficiency limit. No need to wait until the heat death of the universe to notice an infinite growth isn't possible. BTW, I think you meant "state of maximum entropy".

Comment: To be fair, I did say that this opinion wouldn't be popular :D With only 2% or 3% growth, our society crashes against hard physical laws in a few centuries at most, which I would argue is a meaningful time scale.

Comment: "our society crashes against hard physical laws in a few centuries at most, which I would argue is a meaningful time scale." except in some contexts. Such as within the context of a discussion about economics of our current society. Which is exactly the context here. Context is crucial.

Comment: Indefinite exponential growth in efficiency leading to Indefinite exponential economic growth has more problems than simply saying that "Indefinite exponential economic growth is possible". There is far, far less room to improve efficiency than there is room to increase inputs. ie: we'd have to invent entirely new branches of *physics* to increase efficiency that much, not invent new technologies.

Comment: @EricDuminil "With only 2% or 3% growth, our society crashes against hard physical laws in a few centuries at most, which I would argue is a meaningful time scale" If you have any actual facts to back up that assertion, I'd love to see it as an answer.

Comment: @Shane https://dothemath.ucsd.edu/2011/07/can-economic-growth-last/ or https://dothemath.ucsd.edu/2012/04/economist-meets-physicist/ for example. Beware, Tom Murphy might not be well received here.

Comment: @Shane You are shifting the focus of the debate. Yes, major scientific breakthrough are necessary to sustain technology based growth (n.b. in economics a new branch of physics *is* a new technology, so you draw is a false dichotomy). But the question was not whether indefinite exponential growth is likely (again, I think it is not), but whether it is demonstrably impossible as a matter of fact. "It would require new branches of physics and is therefore hard" is not a rigorous demonstration of impossibility. Nor are the writings of Tom Murphy. They are claims about likelihood, not possibility.

Comment: In reality, there are only likelihoods. It isn't impossible for you to walk off the top of Trump tower and to fly away. It isn't impossible for the universe to spontaneously replace itself with a custard pie. It isn't impossible for us to find new physics that will allow for the efficiency gains you describe. But to actually say that it is *possible* for these things to happen renders the word meaningless.

Comment: IOW "Indeed, if technology improves at a sufficient rate then it is (theoretically) possible to sustain exponential economic growth even as the the consumption of inputs decreases faster than exponentially" And "Indeed, if we discover magic from Harry Potter then it is (theoretically) possible to sustain exponential economic growth even as the the consumption of inputs decreases faster than exponentially" are *identical* statements. ie worthless.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what time scales you are talking about, but no.

> "The greatest shortcoming of the human race is our inability to understand the exponential function."
>
> -Albert Allen Bartlett, emeritus professor of physics at the University of Colorado at Boulder, USA.

[Arithmetic, Population and Energy (Youtube)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sI1C9DyIi_8)

You can watch the talk that goes over the math, but the conclusion inescapable: Exponential growth -- consistent growth over time -- cannot proceed indefinitely within a finite system. Ie: planet Earth or the universe.

Even if you (correctly) believe that value doesn't come from gold, you have to agree that it comes from *somewhere*. Eventually, that somewhere/something will run out. Even if you believe that the economy will be digital, and we go green, and come up with sustainable growth of computers and the digital economy, eventually just their waste heat will cook the planet. Forget co2!

**EDIT:**

> Do you mean that we won't be able to build computer chips that can
> store a digital representation of someone's stock income? This
> seems wrong to me.

Yes! That is *exactly* what it means. It means that if you somehow managed to store the value of a digit in one planck length^2 (note this is MANY, MANY,  MANY, orders of magnitude beyond what is theoretically possible, even in theory) eventually, the representation of the value will fill up the ENTIRE universe. Then on the next doubling, you would need ***TWO*** universes to just to contain the representation of the value of the stock market. Then four universes...

The reason this seems wrong to you is because one of the greatest shortcomings of the human race is our inability to understand the exponential function.

---

Even if you can't wrap your head around that:

One day the sun will burn out. One day, the last star will burn out. One day, the universe be totally cold and dark. On that day, even electrons will be too cold to spin around their atom. On that day, all physical processes stop. Yes, that does include the stock market.

---

On that depressing note, I leave you with the parable of the Indian king and his grain.

> There's a famous legend about the origin of chess that goes like this. When the inventor of the game showed it to the emperor of India, the emperor was so impressed by the new game, that he said to the man
>
> "Name your reward!"
>
> The man responded, "Oh emperor, my wishes are simple. I only wish for this. Give me one grain of rice for the first square of the chessboard, two grains for the next square, four for the next, eight for the next and so on for all 64 squares, with each square having double the number of grains as the square before."
>
> The emperor agreed, amazed that the man had asked for such a small reward - or so he thought. After a week, his treasurer came back and informed him that the reward would add up to an astronomical sum, far greater than all the rice that could conceivably be produced in many many centuries!

On the entire chessboard there would be 2^64 − 1 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 grains of wheat, weighing about 1,199,000,000,000 metric tons. This is about 1,645 times the global production of wheat in 2014 (729,000,000 metric tons).

Comment: *Even if you (correctly) believe that value doesn't come from gold, you have to agree that it comes from somewhere.* I don't know what this statement is intended to mean, so no, I don't necessarily agree. Your argument about the wheat doesn't imply that the stock market can't show indefinite exponential growth. Rather, it suggests that if the stock market did so, then the price of wheat would also have to go up exponentially. Wheat is just another commodity, like gold.

Comment: *"If an elderly but distinguished scientist says that something is possible, he is almost certainly right; but if he says that it is impossible, he is very probably wrong."* - Arthur C. Clarke.

Comment: @BenCrowell "I don't know what this statement is intended to mean, so no, I don't necessarily agree." Look up things like Supply and Demand and the price system. tl;dr: *The value of something comes from people valuing said something.* Also, I added a section to the answer answering one specific question from you OP.

Comment: @BenCrowell Oh, and the wheat in that parable stands for the *stock market itself.*

Comment: *"One day the sun will burn out."* Ah, I think you've misunderstood the question. Context is important - it's what gives meaning to everything.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I really like your Arthur C. Clarke's quote, and I think it's very often correct. The laws of thermodynamics are really tough, though, and they often state that something is impossible. It's not an opinion, it's a mathematical and physical law that hasn't been disproved in almost 200 years.

Comment: @EricDuminil but the point is that this is nothing to do with thermodynamics. Only armchair physicists with no grasp of economics think it is. Context is crucial, here.

Comment: @Shane you write *"It depends on what time scales you are talking about"*. The information is implicit in the context. It's so obvious to anyone in the field, that it really shouldn't need stating explicitly. However, it apparently does need stating explicitly. We are talking about the stock market. That in and of itself is a phenomenon that (as far as we can ascertain from history) only has meaning at timescales of milliseconds to centuries. So that's the time scales we are talking about.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I guess it makes the problem clearer : at least armchair physicists try to keep a connection to the real, physical world and don't dare to ignore universal laws. Context is crucial, yes, and the context is the whole physical world with physical laws. Economist: "Look, that's a perpetuum mobile!". Physicist: "Nope, that's not possible". Economist: "You have no grasp of economics!".

Comment: No, it's not a perpetuum mobile - that's the whole point. We are (1) talking about a meaningful timescale of a few centuries at most; and (2) we are talking about economic value - and as intellectual activity can have economic value, its increase does not need to relate to any increase in anything measured in joules or grammes.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: If you have to restrict the problem to a few centuries to avoid the pitfalls posed by indefinite exponential growth, well then, you know what the answer is. But even then, 2 or 3% of growth during a few centuries is nowhere near sustainable for mankind, even if you assume that 1 or 2 % come from intellectual activity.

Comment: It's not a matter of "having to restrict the problem to a few centuries" - that is, again, the crux. Context is everything. The context here is an economics discussion of the stock market. So the timescale is immediately obvious to economists.

Comment: @EricDuminil  Physicists see "indefinite" and think "oh, I know what that means to me, so it must mean the same here". That's not the case. And no, cows aren't spherical, and yes, we are only interested in cases where the number of cows is a non-negative integer. And of course 2-3% growth in the stock market index is achievable over centuries. What do you think the index is an index of? (clue: not things measured in joules or grammes).

Comment: @EnergyNumbers Sorry, I forgot that "indefinite" means hundreds and that "context is important" means "let's ignore any inconvenient fact". 3% over 400 years (which I hope you'll agree is still a long way from infinity) is more than a factor 130000. I never said that the stock market index is measured in Joules or grammes, I dare to say that at least 1/100000 of it is somehow linked to real activities which require oil, gas or electricity.

Comment: @EricDuminil  Context is crucial - that's where the words get their meaning from.  And the stock market index can increase while at the same time, the energy consumed decreases. If you genuinely do want to understand, have a think about what the index is an index of.